# SQL statement for querying with multiple conditions including 3 most recent dates

Tags: mysql, sql, date, greatest-n-per-group, multiple-conditions

I need help in finding the rows that correspond to the most recent date, the next most recent and the one after that, where some condition ABC is "Y" and group it by a column name XYZ ASC but XYZ can appear multiple times. So, say XYZ is 50, then for the rows in the three years, the XYZ will be 50. I have the following code that executes but returns only two rows out of thousands which is impossible. I tried executing just the date condition but it returned dates that were less than or equal to MAX(DATE)-3 as well. Don't know where I am going wrong.

```
select * from money.cash where DATE =(
  select
  MAX(DATE)
  from
  money.cash
  where
  DATE > (select MAX(DATE)-3 from money.cash)
)
GROUP BY XYZ ASC
having ABC = "Y";
```

The structure of the table is as follows (only a schematic, not the real thing).

```
Comp_ID   DATE   XYZ   ABC  $$$$ ....
1     2012-1-1    10    Y   SOME-AMOUNT
2     2011-1-1    10    Y
3     2006-1-1    10    Y
4     2011-1-1    20    Y
5     2002-1-1    20    Y
6     2000-1-1    20    Y
7     1998-1-1    20    Y
```

The desired o/p would be the first three rows for XYZ=10 in ascending order and the most recent 3 dates for XYZ=20.

LAST AND IMPORTANT-This table's values keeps changing as new data comes in. So, the o/p(which will be in a new table) must reflect the dynamics in the 1st/original/above TABLE.

Comment: Need the table structure to give you a proper answer.

Comment: @Tony - The structure is - around 4000 rows with around 10 columns like ABC, XYZ, DATE, company name. The TABLE is 'cash' and 'money' is the schema. There are multiple dates for the same XYZ/company name but I only need the most recent three. Let me know if this doesn't answer your question.

Comment: I think @TonyHopkinson was suggesting that you put some sample data *(with all the relevant fields)* into your question.  Also, if you could then show the example result that you desire?  This would given a concrete example of the logic that you have attempted to describe in English.

Comment: @Dems-It is sensitive data and contains several columns and thousands of rows. But I can provide a schematic as edited below the code above.

Comment: Have you tried something more like SELECT * FROM money.cash WHERE DATE BETWEEN @yourminDateVariable AND GETDATE()

Comment: @MikeSmithDev - Do you mean something like this - SELECT * FROM money.cash WHERE DATE BETWEEN MAX(DATE)-3 AND MAX(DATE) instead of the section of code that reads where DATE =(
>select
>MAX(DATE)
>from
>money.cash
>where
>DATE > (select MAX(DATE)-3 from money.cash)
>)

Comment: This eems like a **[`[greatest-n-per-group]`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group)** problem

Comment: The name of the table and the relevant fields will do, in particular the key. Self join to a limit should be a good way towards this, but I need to know what to join on. and I've just spotted in the question now. Sigh, it's been one of those weeks.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL doesn't have functionallity that is friendly to `greatest-n-per-group` queries.

One option would be...
- Find the `MAX(Date)` per group *(`XYZ`)*
- Then use that result to find the `MAX(Date)` of all records before that date
- Then do it again for all records before that date

It's really innefficient, but MySQL hasn't got the functionality required to do this efficiently.  Sorry...

```
CREATE TABLE yourTable
     (
      comp_id                          INT,
      myDate                           DATE,
      xyz                              INT,
      abc                              VARCHAR(1)
)
;

INSERT INTO yourTable SELECT 1, '2012-01-01', 10, 'Y';
INSERT INTO yourTable SELECT 2, '2011-01-01', 10, 'Y';
INSERT INTO yourTable SELECT 3, '2006-01-01', 10, 'Y';
INSERT INTO yourTable SELECT 4, '2011-01-01', 20, 'Y';
INSERT INTO yourTable SELECT 5, '2002-01-01', 20, 'Y';
INSERT INTO yourTable SELECT 6, '2000-01-01', 20, 'Y';
INSERT INTO yourTable SELECT 7, '1998-01-01', 20, 'Y';


SELECT
  yourTable.*
FROM
(
  SELECT
    lookup.XYZ,
    COALESCE(MAX(yourTable.myDate), lookup.MaxDate)  AS MaxDate
  FROM
  (
    SELECT
      lookup.XYZ,
      COALESCE(MAX(yourTable.myDate), lookup.MaxDate)  AS MaxDate
    FROM
    (
      SELECT
        yourTable.XYZ,
        MAX(yourTable.myDate)  AS MaxDate
      FROM
        yourTable
      WHERE
        yourTable.ABC = 'Y'
      GROUP BY
        yourTable.XYZ
    )
      AS lookup
    LEFT JOIN
      yourTable
        ON  yourTable.XYZ    = lookup.XYZ
        AND yourTable.myDate < lookup.MaxDate
        AND yourTable.ABC    = 'Y'
    GROUP BY
      lookup.XYZ,
      lookup.MaxDate
  )
    AS lookup
  LEFT JOIN
    yourTable
      ON  yourTable.XYZ    = lookup.XYZ
      AND yourTable.myDate < lookup.MaxDate
      AND yourTable.ABC    = 'Y'
  GROUP BY
    lookup.XYZ,
    lookup.MaxDate
)
  AS lookup
INNER JOIN
  yourTable
    ON  yourTable.XYZ     = lookup.XYZ
    AND yourTable.myDate >= lookup.MaxDate
WHERE
  yourTable.ABC = 'Y'
ORDER BY
  yourTable.comp_id
;


DROP TABLE yourTable;
```

There are other options, but they're all a bit hacky.  Search SO for `greatest-n-per-group mysql`.

My results using your example data:

```
Comp_ID | DATE     | XYZ | ABC
------------------------------
   1    | 2012-1-1 | 10  |  Y
   2    | 2011-1-1 | 10  |  Y
   3    | 2006-1-1 | 10  |  Y
   4    | 2011-1-1 | 20  |  Y
   5    | 2002-1-1 | 20  |  Y
   6    | 2000-1-1 | 20  |  Y
```

Comment: Thanks Dems - I get it. But how would I do this for thousands of different values of XYZ? When I try to execute the "greatest-n-per-group", I get more than the **most recent three dates** so yes, the dates are not filtered with the "greatest-n-per-group" statement. When I try to execute the whole code above, it returns only 2 rows out of thousands which is obviously incorrect. So, I need some **one** function that can iterate over all the rows and return the desired rows. Further, the o/p must reflect the dynamic nature of the original table (as schematized above).

Comment: @user1542006 - I'm sorry, I don't understand.  It won't matter how many different values of XYZ there are, the `GROUP BY` takes care of that.  Also, do you *know* that each `XYZ` has atleast three dates?  If not, you'll need a slightly different query, I'll update the answer to cope with that.  As for a single function - MySQL doesn't have one.  As for itterations - Don't use SQL for loops or itterations; SQL is a Set Based expression.  Could you set up a dummy table using the exact same data as your example and try it on that?  Then post the results of this query if there is a problem?

Comment: Okay. Let me try it. Still learning here. Every XYZ does not have three dates-some have more, some fewer.

Comment: I see your edited code above. Would this require entering the actual values in DATE? The actual values under DATE number differently in thousands. I am running your previous code but it has been running for the past 10 minutes and is still running. - Okay. it just finished running and returned 57 rows. I'll have to cross-check the rows against the actual values. Should I put in the "HAVING ABC" clause as I do in the code in question?

Comment: You should always store dates in a native data-type such as DATE or TIMESTAMP, etc.  You should also have an index on `(XYZ, myDate)`.

Comment: When do you want to filter by `ABC = 'Y'`?  After you've found the three dates, or before?  If you want to ignore `ABC <> 'Y'` records when working out the three dates, you need to put it as a `WHERE` clause on every level of the query.  See my latest edit.

Comment: I tried your original code and added the HAVING clause-returned 12 rows in 9 minutes-Too long a time? since I'll have to further specify the columns as well in the new table.

Comment: I think the ABC='Y' clause needs to be executed before the DATE requirement. I can't see your latest edit with the WHERE clause.

Comment: I realised that I need a LEFT JOIN so the condition now appears in there.  I need to go home now, I hope this gives you a start to experiment from.  If you have problems I recommend doing `Just 1 date` until it works, then `2 dates` then `3 dates`.  Good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much - you have been a great help. I'll try with 1,2... dates but am worried that I would have to it for all the dates-thousands of them.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way, hopefully more efficient than Dems' answer.
Test it with an index on `(abc, xyz, date)`:

```
SELECT m.xyz, m.date                --- for all columns:    SELECT m.* 
FROM 
    ( SELECT DISTINCT xyz
      FROM  money.cash
      WHERE abc = 'Y'
    ) AS dm
  JOIN
    money.cash AS m
      ON  m.abc = 'Y'
      AND m.xyz = dm.xyz
      AND m.date >= COALESCE(
            ( SELECT im.date
              FROM  money.cash AS im
              WHERE im.abc = 'Y'
                AND im.xyz = dm.xyz
              ORDER BY im.date DESC
                LIMIT 1 
                OFFSET 2                --- to get 3 latest rows per xyz 
            ), DATE('1000-01-01') ) ;
```

If you have more than rows with same `(abc, xyz, date)`, the query may return more than 3 rows per `xyz` (all tied in 3rd place will all be shown).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I am trying to figure out how to create a dummy table so I can create the indices in it rather than changing the original table.

Comment: The actual O/P would include several other columns but they don't have any conditions attached. Further, 2 things - How does one create dummy tables in MySQL AND the original table's values are dynamic-they (for example, values in DATE, etc.) keep changing - how would I make the new table reflect the dynamics of the original table?

Comment: What do you mean with dynamic tables? Tables have rows inserted, deleted, updated all the time.

Comment: By 'dynamic', I mean rows changing their values as you said. But also that the new table generated with the help of the code above (not created as yet) reflects the changing values in the original table in real time.

Comment: That is not possible in MySQL. It is (with a View) but you can't index a view.

Comment: So, you can just copy a table and then index the copy. No real time changes though. Just frozen data.